# VBA Code to Insert Image in Placeholder

Tags: vba

I am working with VBA for the first time and have created a User Form that includes two drop down menus along with a Command Button. Once the user selects an item from each drop down menu ("Image1" and "Image2" for example) they will then click the command button, which would insert those selected items (which are images that would be pulled from a file on the local computer) inside specific image placeholders that are on the slide.

Any ideas on how I would make this happen? I currently have the form designed, but it has zero functionality. I hope this is clear. Thanks!

--UPDATE--

Here is the VBA code I have so far. The next question is where do I link the files, such as "Ash Fork", to local images on the computer:

```
Private Sub Combo1_DropButtonClick()
With Combo1

    .AddItem "Ash Fork"
    .AddItem "Flagstaff"
    .AddItem "Winslow"
    .AddItem "Clints Well"
    .AddItem "Bellemont"

End With
End Sub

Private Sub Combo2_DropButtonClick()
With Combo2

    .AddItem "Ash Fork"
    .AddItem "Flagstaff"
    .AddItem "Winslow"
    .AddItem "Clints Well"
    .AddItem "Bellemont"

End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim image1 As String
Dim image2 As String

image1 = Combo1.Text
image2 = Combo2.Text

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=image1, _
                              linktofile:=msoFalse, _
                              savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
                              Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=100

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=image2, _
                              linktofile:=msoFalse, _
                              savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
                              Left:=0, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=100

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I finally came upon this, which does the job!

```
  Private Sub Combo1_DropButtonClick()

    If Combo1.ListCount = 0 Then
        With Combo1
            .AddItem "Ash Fork"
            .AddItem "Flagstaff"
            .AddItem "Winslow"
            .AddItem "Clints Well"
            .AddItem "Bellemont"

        End With
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Combo2_DropButtonClick()

    If Combo2.ListCount = 0 Then
        With Combo2
            .AddItem "Ash Fork"
            .AddItem "Flagstaff"
            .AddItem "Winslow"
            .AddItem "Clints Well"
            .AddItem "Bellemont"

        End With
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  'Insert webcam for Combo1.
  If Combo1 = "Flagstaff" Then
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="K:\ALL PICTURES\Keeper_Photos\General Pictures\Aspens.jpg", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=60, Top:=0, _
   Width:=98, Height:=48).Select

  ElseIf Combo1 = "Ash Fork" Then
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="K:\ALL PICTURES\Keeper_Photos\General Pictures\gcanyon3.jpg", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=60, Top:=0, _
   Width:=98, Height:=48).Select

  End If

  'Insert webcam for Combo2.
  If Combo2 = "Flagstaff" Then
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="K:\ALL PICTURES\Keeper_Photos\General Pictures\Aspens.jpg", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=60, Top:=0, _
   Width:=98, Height:=48).Select

  ElseIf Combo2 = "Ash Fork" Then
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="K:\ALL PICTURES\Keeper_Photos\General Pictures\gcanyon3.jpg", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=60, Top:=0, _
   Width:=98, Height:=48).Select

  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to this in your command button event:

```
Dim image1 As String
Dim image2 As String

image1 = ComboBox1.Text
image2 = ComboBox2.Text

ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=image1, _
                                   linktofile:=msoFalse, _
                                   savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
                                   Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=100

ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=image2, _
                                   linktofile:=msoFalse, _
                                   savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
                                   Left:=0, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=100
```

Comment: Alright, awesome. So I guess my next question would be: How and where would I link the text in the drop down box to a file location on the computer? Would this be within the combobox code? For instance, in each drop down box there will be about 15 options, each is linked to a different image. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to populate you ComboBox?

Comment: I just added all the code I have so far in an update to the original post. I need to set the text within the drop downs (Ash Fork for instance) to be associated with an image file on the computer (located at say: C:\images\AshFork.png). This way when you click the command button, it will take your selection in each combo and insert that image in the place holder.

Comment: I eddited my answer based on your comment

Comment: Oh, ok. So I can't do this all within PPT, I need to have an excel file as well?

Comment: You can asign the path string directly to the ComboBox then you don't need an worksheet.

Comment: I eddited my answer again, I haven't noticed that you were using ppt, 
I thought you were using Excel. Using ppt I don't know how you can get the path based on other string.

Comment: Ok. I'll keep searching. Thanks for all your help!